# Django 1.5 loses data from a form

Tags: jquery, django

Using Django 1.5 and JQuery, I'm unable to retrieve data from a form in my views.

My HTML code is:

```
<form method="post" class="form-inline" id="getemailbutton" onsubmit="getemail();return     false">
<input type="text" id="email" class="input-small" placeholder="Email" />
<button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn" >Go!</button></form><!-- end of email form -->
```

My JS code is:

```
function getemail(){
    div = 'getemailbutton';
    ending="Thanks! We will contact you asap.";
    console.log($('#email').val());
    $('span#getemailbutton').css('display','none');
    $('#getemailbutton').html(ending).fadeIn();
    $.post("/getemail/",{ "email" : $('#email').val() });
}
```

My code for the view is:

```
def getemail(request):
    email = request.POST['email']
    message = ("New lead by email:%s\n" % email)
    Mail(message)
    return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

My urls.py is the following:
    from web import views

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),
    url(r'^index/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),
    url(r'^features/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="features.html")),
    url(r'^offer/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="offer.html")),
    url(r'^whatfor/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="whatfor.html")),
    url(r'^contact/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="contact.html")),
    url(r'^getemail/', views.getemail, name="getemail"),
    url(r'^getphone/', views.getphone, name="getphone"),
```

The beginning of the error is:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /getemail/
"Key 'email' not found in <QueryDict: {}>"

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/getemail/
Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Executable: /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path: ['/home/chaica/progra/python/backupchecker', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_blog_zinnia-0.13.dev-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']
Server time: lun, 28 Oct 2013 09:53:34 +0100
Installed Applications:
('web',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')

Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  77.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/chaica/progra/python/backupchecker/web/views.py" in getemail
  11.     email = request.POST['email']
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py" in __getitem__
  295.             raise MultiValueDictKeyError("Key %r not found in %r" % (key, self))

Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /getemail/
Exception Value: "Key 'email' not found in <QueryDict: {}>"
Request information:
GET: No GET data

POST: No POST data

FILES: No FILES data

COOKIES:
csrftoken = 'rfF4e8hzbSI77uszQd1LxFdodw02nfJa'

Context:
```

- CSRF is disable for debugging purpose, I'll turn it on later
- With Firebug, I see that data coming from the HTML to the JS script works, because the good values appear in the console.log() of the JS.
- I suspect something about Django, maybe url redirection but I can't find what's wrong with my setting.

Comment: You shoudl always end all your url regees with `/$`.

Comment: limelights: tried that too, It's the same. Byt thanks for the info, I'm updating the question.

Comment: You could divide problem into 2 parts if you take a look at firebug network section, where each request appears. if parameter with right name is present in request - than problem is on server side and vice versa.

Comment: Admit: as you can read in the stack trace, the request method is post and the POST dict is empty, which is weird because the JS seems to work by itself

Comment: but please verify, is parameter goes from browser? if it does, you could remove front-end part from question and concentrate on server part.

Answer (score 1):

here's your problem: you call `console.log` in the beginning so you can really see that `$("#email").val()` exists, but THEN you remove `email` input by calling that `$('#getemailbutton').html(ending)`. So in the end, when `$.post()` is called, `$("#email")` doesn't exist anymore.
Save that value into some variable, which you can use later:

```
function getemail(){
    div = 'getemailbutton';
    ending="Thanks! We will contact you asap.";
    console.log($('#email').val());
    var email = $('#email').val()'
    $('span#getemailbutton').css('display','none');
    $('#getemailbutton').html(ending).fadeIn();
    $.post("/getemail/",{ "email" : email });
}
```

Comment: yedpodtrzitko has got it, but might I suggest changing the order of your operations? Why not do the post first, then change the `#getemailbutton` on success. It may be more robust, and will allow you to catch problems it the post fails.

Comment: yedpodtrzitko: That was related to that issue you described. Thanks a lot!